# Angular 5 | Check if a field exists in a Cloud Firestore

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, validation, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently working on a big project and for that, I need to work with Firebase and Angular 5, but I'm blocking a bit about form validation.

I would like to create a custom validator to check if the email that the user enters is already used.

For this, I put a function in the custom validators, the error is displayed when the email is already used, but it is when we enter an address that is not used that there is a problem.

When I validate the form with an address already used, the form returns me the status: "INVALID", which is quite normal and that's what I look for, but when I validate with an email that is not in Firestore, it returns an error telling me that the form is in status "PENDING", that is to say it wait .. But wait for what?

**What I do**

I create my formControl in my template

```
// inscription.component.html
<mat-step [stepControl]="form">
  <form [formGroup]="form">
    <mat-form-field>
       <input matInput formControlName="email" 
       placeholder="Ton adresse email" required>
       <mat-error *ngIf="email.invalid">
         {{ getErrorMessage(email, 'adresse email', 3, 25) }}
       </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
  </form>
</mat-step>
```

My function getErrorMessage()

```
// inscription.component.html
getErrorMessage(selector: any, element: string, minCharacters: number, maxCharacters: number) {
     return selector.hasError('required') ? 'Tu dois entrer ton ' + element :
            selector.hasError('notunique') ? 'Cette ' + element + ' est déjà utilisée' :
            '';
}
```

I initialize everything I need to create the form :

```
// inscription.component.ts
form: FormGroup;
email = new FormControl('', [
   Validators.required,
   Validators.email,
   Validators.minLength(3),
   Validators.maxLength(25)
   // Fonction pour la vérif de l'email
], this.checkIfEmailExistsInDatabase.bind(this));
```

Then I initialize the formControl "email" in my form

```
// inscription.component.ts
ngOnInit() {
   this.form = new FormGroup({
      email: this.email,
   });
}
```

And finally ... where does the "bug" come from :

```
// inscription.component.ts
    checkIfEmailExistsInDatabase(control: AbstractControl) {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            // We check that there is no document with the same name of what is in the formControl
            firebase.firestore().collection('items').where('email', '==', control.value).get()
                .then(snapshot => {
                    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                        if (!doc.exists) {
                            console.log('Email doesn\'t exists');
                            resolve(null);
                            // ERROR: Validation status remains in "PENDING"                                // While he must normally proceed to the next step
                        } else {
                            console.log('Email exists already');
                            resolve({ 'notunique' : true });
                            // An error message is displayed well and blocks validation                            }
                    })
                });
        });
    }
```

I confess that I do not really understand why I do not understand where I can get this bug, if it's a bug, and how to fix it..:?

Sorry for my bad English, I'm French.

If you have an idea don't hesitate to answer, thank you in advance!